# How can I connect two switches with the STP enabled over one port, and without blocking ports

Tags: switch, ethernet, stp

I have a question, if I want to connect two boards and each board has internal switch(like below topology), as you know that in general, the switch might have STP(Spanning Tree Protocol) enabled in order to avoid broadcast storm, but, if the STP is enabled on all ports, does that mean I cannot send packets from NIC1 to NIC2 thru all 10 ports at the same time, or, only one port will be available and other ports will be blocked by STP feature. But if I disable the STP, then it will get broadcast storm, is my understanding correct?

[image]

If it is correct, I'd like to know, if there is other way, to let all connections available, when all ports are still STP enabled.

==============================================

Update:

Thanks @vidarlo and @jbgeek, now I understand to use Link Aggregation Group (LAG) to bind all ports as a virtual port, so it can ignore the STP function for the connection.

But except the LAG, for example on below screenshot, the port 2~8 are configured with VLAN20, so I expect to get connection block when I connect port 2~8 to another switch, and I would like to know, if I configure each port with different VLANs, i.e. port 2 with VLAN30, port 3 with VLAN40...etc., and then connect these ports to another switch, can it avoid the STP blocking, to let all ports available?

[image]

Thanks,
Jacky

Comment: If you want to use multiple ports as one channel your switches need to support link aggregation, and that had to be configured.

Comment: @vidarlo question: if switch ports can be configured with link aggregation, how many ports can be configured as a logical port? For example, as the topology, if I config two ports(port 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6...etc.) with link aggregation, then there will be 5 logical ports, so, when I connect both NICs thru 5 logical ports, then it will not have STP blocking issue? Or, I need to configure all ports 1~10 as a logical port, and connect one logical port each other?

Comment: Read your manual. Additionally, you should probably note that will not give you 10 times the bandwidth for any single connection.

Comment: @vidarlo understood, so the only way is to set the link aggregation group (LAG) to combine all 10 ports as a virtual port, but as you said the bandwidth will not be 10 times, thank you very much.

Comment: If a port is only used for a single VLAN, you don't risk a broadcast storm.

Comment: @vidarlo No, I mean that if I still need to let all ports work individually, not block by STP, and not using link aggregation group, can I configure each port with different vLAN, to achieve the need?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? This sounds like X-Y problem...

Comment: @vidarlo You said: "If a port is only used for a single VLAN, you don't risk a broadcast storm.", sorry, I got your point now, I think you mean that if every port works for a single VLAN, i.e. port 1 with VLAN10: 172.16.10.x, port 2 with LAN20: 172.16.20.x, then I don't risk a broadcast storm, that means, I need to configure different VLAN to NIC1 all switch ports, and no need to configure NIC2, NIC2 port will be assigned IP from NIC1 per different VLAN, then it should work on every ports, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If STP is enabled, and every port is on the same vLAN, all but one link connecting the two switches will be disabled to prevent forwarding loops.

If that port loses link, another pair will be enabled (if the intent is high redundancy).

There are various protocols that can be used to bundle multiple links together into a virtual single link for more bandwidth, if that's what your aim is.

This wiki article has a good overview of link aggregation mechanisms:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation

Comment: Got it, understand that the LAG might be the only way to avoid it, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, additional question, you said: "every port is on the same vLAN", does that mean if I can configure each port with different vLAN/IP subnet(i.e. port 1 with IP 1.1.1.x, port2 with IP 2.2.2.x and so on), then it will not have STP blocking issue?

Comment: Sorry, not the IP subnet, just the different VLANs by different DHCP.

Comment: Computers expect that a subnet corresponds to a broadcast domain. I have no idea what you're attempting to achieve, but it sounds like you are on the wrong path.

Comment: @vidarlo As your suggestion, you said that the LAG should be the solution to avoid STP blocking when connecting two switches each other thru multiple ports, but my question is, except the LAG, is there any other way that to let two switch ports connected each other, but would not happen broadcast storm(like what we said here: STP), and also able to send/receive packets on each individual port(not block by STP) on both switches?

Comment: Originally, I thought that if I can make each port with different vLAN thru internal DHCP on both switches, but this might be wrong, because it will be conflict when two switches are with DHCP enabled and each ports configured with different vLAN, then it might be no connection when connecting both switches.

Comment: Your setup and ideas makes no sense to me. What are you actually attempting to do?

Comment: @vidarlo Sorry, I am new in Ethernet switch area, please forgive me for my stupid questions.....>/<, it would be appreciated if you could guide me, how to connect two switches with STP enabled, but still can let all connected ports available individually, but not only one port available, and others are blocked, except the LAG function, I'd need each ports work well individually when the STP feature is enabled, or, is there other way can achieve it with STP disabled on both switches?

Comment: ***WHY*** do you want to connect them like this?

Comment: @vidarlo Because I need to verify the HW function including performance and full load stress tests, of course, the another way is, to connect each ports to external NIC card, but it would need to buy more cards to fulfill all switch ports, the easier way for me is, because I have the two same NIC with embedded switch like what I post the screenshot above, so I'd to understand if any way can connect both NICs with each port availability, and to perform the tests on each ports, i.e. to full load stress all ports.

Comment: This doesn't sound like system administration, but rather testing and development. Furthermore, it seems you have no or little understanding of the system under test - a bad combination...

Comment: @vidarlo sorry....my bad. >/<